# Cucumber-Why does automation browser not launch on running the testrunner class

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have created a sample cucumber test with a feature file,glueclass and test runner class.As is the normal case running test runner class I see that result is set to run but browser is not launched screenshot below.
[image]

However I am able to launch it from feature file.
I am not able to understand why this is happening. 
Please find below the project structure

[image]

Feature file :

```
Feature: Login Action

Scenario Outline: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User enters "<UserName>" and Password
    Then Message displayed Login Successfully

Examples:

| UserName |

| Rob      |

| Bob      |
| Cob      |
```

Glue class:

```
package loginpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class Logintest {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^User is on Home Page$")
    public void user_is_on_Home_Page() throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("Value in portal :");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\FireKWDemo\\ext\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }

    @When("^User enters \"([^\"]*)\" and Password$")
    public void user_enters_UserName_and_Password(String q) throws Throwable {

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(q);
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
    }

    @Then("^Message displayed Login Successfully$")
    public void message_displayed_Login_Successfully() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println("Test Successful");
        driver.close();
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things that chrome needs. First, you need to tell Selenium where it can find the chromedriver.exe that you previously downloaded and installed.  This is what I have on one system that I am running. Give it a try and let us know if that fixed it.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "C:\\User\you\\drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
prefs.put("excludeSwitches", "enable-automation");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("version", "latest");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

try {
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("**>uh-oh " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Obviously, replace "C:\\User\you\\drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe" with the full path of where you installed chromedriver.exe.

Comment: I had already entered the path.It's there in the code attached.Actually I am able to launch the browser when I run it through the feature file.But as is the normal case I am not able to launch it from testrunner class.I am not able to understand why this is happening.On running through testrunner class I get that  first screen shot I attached.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your step definition path in test runner class? It's missing in the given screenshot.

Use the following info in test runner class:

```
features =     "/Users/NaveenKhunteta/Documents/workspace/CucumberPOM/src/main/java/com/qa/features/freecrm.feature", //the path of the feature files
    glue={"com/qa/stepDefinitions"}, //the path of the step definition files
    format= {"pretty","html:test-outout", "json:json_output/cucumber.json", "junit:junit_xml/cucumber.xml"}, //to generate different types of reporting
    monochrome = true, //display the console output in a proper readable format
    strict = true, //it will check if any step is not defined in step definition file
    dryRun = false //to check the mapping is proper between feature file and step def file
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you commented the line for **glue** option?

Remove the comment for glue option and you should add the **tag** for running the test. It is also not provided. Add the **tag** from the feature file for the Scenario in the **runner class** and check.

Answer (score 0):

`glue` option should be declared.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(features="src/Feature",glue={"Stepdefination"},
plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json" },
monochrome = true
)
```